# How to get object key if their value matched with our variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a object as given below:

```
const obj = {
        "one@gmail.com": "email one",
        "two@gmail.com": "email two",
}
```

How to get object key if their value matched with given variable:

```
var outputVal = "email two"; 
    Object.entries(obj ).map(([key,value])=>{
          if(outputVal === value){
            console.log('output', key);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason the keys/values can't be the other way around? Much easier to work with.

Comment: You are almost there. Instead of logging the key, store it in a variable on the same level as `outputVal` (which is not output at all, but input, in this piece of code).

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find()` on `Object.keys(obj)`

```js
const obj = {
        "one@gmail.com": "email one",
        "two@gmail.com": "email two",
}

const value = "email two";

const keyMatch = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k] === value);
console.log(keyMatch);
```

Comment: Use `filter()` instead of `find()` if there can be more than 1 matching value.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be simplified by swapping the keys/values around. Just interrogate the object key to get its value.

```js
const obj = {
  "email one": "one@gmail.com",
  "email two": "two@gmail.com"
}

const query = "email two";
console.log(obj[query]);
```

Comment: `const invert = (obj) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]))` can be used if you need to invert the object. Note that only the last key is preserved when encountering duplicate values. `invert({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 1 }) //=> { 1: "c", 2: "b" }`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) since there could be multiple properties with a  value matching your criteria.

```js
const obj = {
  "one@gmail.com": "email one",
  "two@gmail.com": "email two",
}

const query = "email two";
const hits = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] === query);

console.log(hits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine

```js
const obj = {
  "one@gmail.com": "email one",
  "two@gmail.com": "email two",
}

var outputVal = "email two";

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (outputVal === value) {
    console.log('output', key);
  }
})
```

You can use find on object

```js
const obj = {
  "one@gmail.com": "email one",
  "two@gmail.com": "email two",
};
var outputVal = "email two";
const key = Object.keys(obj).find(item => obj[item] === outputVal);
console.log(key);
```

Comment: @axiac this shows no problem with logic, it is working fine

Comment: You're second snippet is not *working fine*. OP asks for matching keys not a value.